# ASP.NET MVC Data Entity design

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, entity

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and want to make it as flexible as possible.

I created abstract database access classes and separate concrete implementations of them (SQL Server access).

This works well with ninject, which automatically binds the correct implementation to the constructed controllers.

The problem I'm now solving is that one of my entities (User entity) has multiple related entities (Task entity) (a 1xn relationship), so I wanted to create a property on this entity class that would return a collection of all related Tasks of a User.

The problem is, that in entity I have no way to find the correct implementation of database access.

What would be the right approach here?

I know it is possible to create a method that returns the Tasks, but this method would also have to have a parameter that would represent the concrete database implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing something here. The domain objects (User,Tasks,etc) and how and where you persist them (access database in this case) are two different things.

Because, as you said , you are developing a "flexible" architecture base on N Layers I would suggest you to focus on design you domain objects not caring to much on how they will be represented on you DB (probably a one-to-many relationship).

In this case your `User` class will have a property which will represent a list of `Tasks`.